wrap text in column for display flex
Below is the code snippet from html file with jinja template. I'm using flex display. I want to wrap the data in column "Resource Name". How can I implement this?


.table-container-0 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.row-item-b {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="table-container-0">
  <p></p>
  <div class="table-row heading">
    <div class="row-item-h2">Resource Name</div>
    <div class="row-item-h2">Class</div>
    <div class="row-item-h2">Access</div>
  </div>
  {% for usrres in usrress %}
  <div class="table-row">
    {% for value in usrres %}
    <div class="row-item-b">{{ value }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>




You could use the word-wrap along with the width css property to achieve the desired behaviour


    .table-container-0 {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      background-color: white;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    }

    .table-row {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    }

    /* .row-item-b {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px 0;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    } */

    .row-item-b {
      flex: 1;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 8px 0;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      width: 33%;
    }
  <div class="table-container-0">
    <p></p>
    <div class="table-row heading">
      <div class="row-item-h2">Resource Name</div>
      <div class="row-item-h2">Class</div>
      <div class="row-item-h2">Access</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">

      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevaluevaluevalueva luevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluev aluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevalu evaluevaluevaluevalue value valuevaluevaluev aluevaluevaluevalue}}
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">

      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevalueval uevaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevalu evaluevaluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevaluevalu evaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevaluevaluev aluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevaluev aluevaluevaluevalue value valuevaluevalueva luevaluevaluevalue}}
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="table-row">

      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevaluevalu evaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevalueval uevaluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevalueval uevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevaluevalu evaluevaluevalue }}
      </div>
      <div class="row-item-b">{{ value valuevaluevalueva luevaluevaluevaluevalue valuevaluevalueval uevaluevaluevalue }}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



